# How to do ten times click the button on Espresso UI test? Is it possible?

Tags: android, android-espresso, uitest

I want to click a button ten times for testing the UI. Is it possible?
If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

You can set a loop with some delay. something like this.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    onView(ViewMatchers.withId(<button_id>)).perform(click());
    SystemClock.sleep(<someDelay milliseconds>);
}
```